# Can foreach loop contain value as an object?

Tags: php

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {


}
```

In this can the $value be an object like the following given below ,
where 10 is the key and other is value

```
[10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 80
            [type] => create_an_account
        )
```

Is this valid ??

Comment: the short answer is yes

Comment: Yes this is valid syntax.

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would love to make a long answer but I can't develop more than: Yes it is. For your culture, this is extract from the [`foreach` doc](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. **foreach works only on arrays and objects**, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable. There are two syntaxes:

Before asking on SO, you can try by yourself :)

Comment: This isn't an *acceptable* answer - should be a comment

Comment: "Yes it is" is actually an anwser.

Comment: Perhaps it is one, but for sure this should have been a comment ...

Comment: In SO, this isn't an acceptable answer

Comment: Guys but downvotes wasn't neccessary though.

Comment: If we forget that this kind of question aren't acceptable on SO (but already flagged, so didn't have to do this...), what kind of answer would you post? Nothing?

Comment: @MaximeLorant Yes, nothing would have been better. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Nice edit

Comment: Re-read this FAQ page and edit my post in consequence indeed. I think there's no more to add now.